# C# Console Menu: Escaping loop after single run

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to write a simple, arrow-driven options menu for a C#.NET console application. Given a dictionary of options to a character return type, users would choose an option with their up/down keys, and select it with Enter.

Problem is, the switch statement breaks out of the program completely after the first run. I've tried placing breakpoints and figuring it out, to no avail-

---

> EDIT: Decided to separate out this code from some of the async code
>   that was also written into the class. For whatever reason, that lets
>   it work as intended, so.. now I need to figure out why async would be
>   messing with this, there's no await needed for a sync operation like
>   this..

---

Code:

```
    static char GetUserInput(Dictionary<char, String> options, int indent = 1) {

        int optionAreaTop = Console.CursorTop;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

        // First option, makes sure it's set in yellow
        bool fo = true;

        foreach (String opt in options.Values) {
            Console.WriteLine(opt.PadLeft(indent + opt.Length, '\t'));
            if (fo) { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; fo = false; }
        }


        return DoMenu(options, optionAreaTop);

    }

    static char DoMenu(Dictionary<char, String> options, int optionAreaTop = 0) {
        int answerIndex = 0;
        int currentAnswerTop = optionAreaTop;
        int indent = 2;
        while (true) {

            ConsoleKeyInfo kin = Console.ReadKey(true);
            ConsoleKey ki = kin.Key;

            switch (ki) {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (currentAnswerTop - 1 >= optionAreaTop) {
                        // Rewrite selection in white
                        WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex), ConsoleColor.White);
                        WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop - 1, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex - 1), ConsoleColor.Yellow);
                        currentAnswerTop -= 1;
                        answerIndex -= 1;
                    }
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    if (answerIndex + 1 < options.Count - 1) {
                        // Rewrite selection in white
                        WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex), ConsoleColor.White);
                        WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop + 1, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex + 1), ConsoleColor.Yellow);
                        currentAnswerTop += 1;
                        answerIndex += 1;
                    }

                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    return options.Keys.ElementAt(answerIndex);

                default:
                    // Retry
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void WriteOptionLine(int position, int indent, String option, ConsoleColor color) {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, position);
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(option.PadLeft(indent + option.Length, '\t'));
    }
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<char, String> opts = new Dictionary<char, string>();
opts.Add('r', "[R]etry the Download");
opts.Add('m', "[M]anually add the file");
opts.Add('s', "[S]kip the file");

// GET_USER_INPUT
char choice = GetUserInput(opts, 2);

// DO WHATEVER
```

Comment: You must be getting an Enter Key.

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. How did you debug your program and what have you find out?

Comment: What is the problem , can you clarify little a bit ?

Comment: Maybe offtopic, but why not try: https://github.com/splttingatms/EasyConsole or other packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code except one, As I have tested it in my console app the last option never can be selected because of your `if` condition in `ArrowDown` so it would be changed like :

```
 case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
          if (answerIndex + 1 <= options.Count - 1)
          {
               // Rewrite selection in white
               WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex), ConsoleColor.White);
               WriteOptionLine(currentAnswerTop + 1, indent, options.Values.ElementAt(answerIndex + 1), ConsoleColor.Yellow);
               currentAnswerTop += 1;
               answerIndex += 1;
          }
          break;
```

the `if (answerIndex + 1 < options.Count - 1)` should be `if (answerIndex + 1 <= options.Count - 1)`

It is obvious that by pressing the Enter key console app will be exited because you are returning from `DoMenu` by `return options.Keys.ElementAt(answerIndex);`  and `choice` variable would be selected option.

Comment: Noticed that in a quick debug, whoops. Don't code at 5am, folks.